# Background-color для селекта

Tags: javascript, css

Как задать фон селекта в зависимости от выбранного элемента? Например если сделать так

```
#some-select option:first-child{
  background-color: #FFEBFA;
}
```

то изменится фон первого элемента в выпадающем списке. Нужно сменить фон самого селекта, при выборе первого элемента.

Comment: Может пример какой-нибудь приведите...

Comment: @AGS17 вот так выглядит селект http://joxi.ru/vAWp1jLCJE6ErW, если выбран какой-либо из элементов. хотелось бы, при выбранной "1", менять фон/шрифт

Comment: Насколько я знаю, без JS тут не обойтись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данный момент с помощью css это сделать **нельзя**, но в будущем будет доступен псевдо-класс **:has()**, которым по задумке можно будет воспользоваться так:

```
select:has(> .red:checked)
{
    background: red;
}
```

Что означает, если элемент select является родителем выбранного элемента с классом red(в вашем случае option), то описуем для него стили.

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

С помощью jquery это можно сделать примерно так:

```js
$('.select').change(function() {
  var selectedColor = $('.select option:selected').val();
  $('.select').css('background', selectedColor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
        <option selected="selected" value="--">--</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="grey">grey</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: здесь происходит выделение в самом выпадающем списке, а мне надо менялся цвет фона на самом селекте

Comment: @cruim, ответ изменен, теперь изменяется именно фон select'a